# Borderlands Mac OS X version play online with Windows version?

Tags: borderlands

I'm unable to find this information specified somewhere.

Basically, the Borderlands version purchaseable through the Mac App Store, can it play with Borderlands installations running on Windows, ie. co-op, etc.?

Or can Mac version only play with Mac, and same for Windows version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steps:

1. Install [GameRanger](http://www.gameranger.com/)
2. Join a room together in GameRanger.
3. You host the game, and make sure you check the box for "Allow late joiners"
   When you start the game, it should launch Borderlands, and your game should jump right to a hosting mode where GameRanger starts up a LAN game. Meanwhile, your friend's game will launch. If they get stuck at the start screen instead of joining you automatically, have them close Borderlands and then launch it again from within Steam.

GameRanger basically sets up a VPN connection between the parties involved, then connects the players via the LAN Game function. So it can be pretty tricky to get working with various routers, ports, firewalls, etc.

Source: http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=117273

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a bit of a hit and miss setup involved here, think I'll see if any of my friends have the PC version and haven't told me and test it before talking the rest into purchasing it.

Comment: @Lasse The game is great! Even on single player! You won't regret :-) I would go for GOTY edition!

Comment: No, I have Borderlands :) I'm just wondering if I talk my friends into buying it we can play together.

Comment: Would you be able to edit the relevants contents of the thread into your answer as well? Links sometimes die, and that way the content would be preserved.

Comment: @Fallen Sure, I will do it...

Comment: Can you play co-op between Mac and Windows versions without using GameRanger?

Comment: @musta: Yes. I did this last night. We set up a VPN using Hamachi. I (sole Mac user) had to host the game, and my Windows friends just passed my Hamachi IP address to Borderlands as a commandline argument (technically, a steam launcher argument?). I haven't found a way to pass the IP address to Mac Borderlands (GameRanger does, so it is possible), which is why I hosted. I've also set up a vpn server using vpnd (already installed on your Mac), but have not yet tested it in Borderlands. Since vpnd replaces the current network link in ControlPanel, I'm hoping this will be even smoother.