# How can I play Borderlands between a Mac and PC over LAN?

Tags: borderlands

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Borderlands Mac OS X version play online with Windows version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/borderlands-mac-os-x-version-play-online-with-windows-version)

I am trying to play a game of Borderlands over LAN with an Ethernet cord. My friend owns a PC and I have a Mac. I connected us up and checked if we'd established a LAN, then I launched Borderlands and clicked on LAN game, but he can't find me. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: My googling tells me that for Mac and PC to play they have to use a piece of software called  GameRanger as GameSpy does not work on the Mac version. I have never used this so I can not help beyond that. If you do find the answer yourself please remember you can answer your own question.